# XML to JSON in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xmlreader

I get XmlReader whith data. How to convert it to JSON in ASP.NET Core MVC?

For example:

```c#
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Sample for XML AUTO", connection as SqlConnection)){
    XmlReader xml = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
    xml.Read();
    //convert xml.ReadOuterXml() to json
    return new ObjectResult(json);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found a solution that worked for me, hope its what you're looking for. The output would be:

> {"something":"someValue"}

```
// References:
//using System.Xml;
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
//using System.Xml.Linq;

var input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><example><something>someValue</something></example>";
using (var xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(input))) {                    
    // This line skips the XML declaration, eg "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" - you can skip this if you don't have declaration as in your case
    xReader.MoveToContent();
    // Gets the actual XMLElement, if any
    xReader.Read();
    // Convert the xReader to an XNode for the Json serializer
    XNode node = XNode.ReadFrom(xReader);
    // Json output
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(node);
    return jsonText;
}
```